# advantages of ApplySides?

Tags: core-language

Version 11.3 introduces `ApplySides` for situations where I usually use `Map`. What is an example where `ApplySides` cannot be replaced by `Map`?

Comment: My understanding is that these functions were introduced for the main purpose to make it easier for new users and school/college students to use Mathematica to work with and manipulate basic equations. Wolfram himself said something to this effect in one of his design review videos on these functions https://www.twitch.tv/videos/207012986  (45:05). They are higher level, more abstract than manipulating the structure directly using map and threading and pure functions. I do not think there is a performance advantage, but they simplify common operations on equations. No time to give examples.

Comment: This function will behave differently for expressions with `Piecewise` or `ConditionalExpression` for example. Also, examine the FullForm of `0 < x <= 1` and note that `Map` would not do what you want in this case.

Comment: @ChipHurst Aha.  I focused on `Equal` and was unaware of the structure of the undocumented `Inequality` (which in any case is a risky application).

Comment: Yes, for `Equal` then it is equivalent to `Map`. Would it make sense to turn my above comment into an answer?

Comment: @ChipHurst I think it would.

Comment: @Nasser This could turn into a teacher's nightmare when students start doing `ApplySides[ Minus, x > y]`... because all the other `*Sides` operations work differently (they don't just do mapping)...

Comment: @Nasser Quite; that's what I had in mind as a "risky application".

Answer (score 7):

`ApplySides` knows more about *mathematical* expressions than `Map`, which is a *structural* operation. For example it knows how to handle heads like `Piecewise`, `ConditionalExpression`, `Inequality`, etc.

```
ApplySides[Sin, Piecewise[{{x^2 < 1, x > 2}}, x^3 > 1]]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{Sin[x^2] < Sin[1], x > 2}}, Sin[x^3] > Sin[1]]
> ```

```
ApplySides[Sin, ConditionalExpression[x^2 == 1, x != 0]]
```

> ```
>  ConditionalExpression[Sin[x^2] == Sin[1], x != 0]
> ```

```
ApplySides[Sin, 0 < x <= 1]
```

> ```
> 0 < Sin[x] <= Sin[1]
> ```

And here's `Map` (at level 1):

```
Map[Sin, Piecewise[{{x^2 < 1, x > 2}}, x^3 > 1]]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{Sin[x^2 < 1], Sin[x > 2]}}, Sin[x^3 > 1]]
> ```

```
Map[Sin, ConditionalExpression[x^2 == 1, x != 0]]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[Sin[x^2 == 1], Sin[x != 0]]
> ```

```
Map[Sin, 0 < x <= 1]
```

> ```
> Inequality[0, Sin[Less], Sin[x]] && Inequality[Sin[x], Sin[LessEqual], Sin[1]]
> ```

Additionally note that `ApplySides` cousins `AddSides`, `SubtractSides`, `MultiplySides`, `DivideSides` will never give a wrong answer, whereas `ApplySides` (and `Map`) can.

```
ApplySides[a*# &, b < c]
```

> ```
> a b < a c
> ```

```
Map[a*# &, b < c]
```

> ```
> a b < a c
> ```

```
MultiplySides[b < c, a]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{a*b < a*c, a > 0}, {a*c < a*b, a < 0}}, b < c]
> ```